# SFTP polling is not working with Spring Integration 6.0.1

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, sftp, polling

Hello I am using file poller with Spring Integration and we have recently migrated to Java 17. Spring Integration moved from 5.5.15 to 6.0.1

My old bean was:

```
@Bean  
public SessionFactory<LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory(){ 
   DefaultSftpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();  
   sf.setHost(serverhost);  
   sf.setPort(portname); 
   sf.setUser(username);
   Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource(sftpKeyPrivateKey); 
   sf.setPrivateKey(resource); 
   sf.setPrivateKeyPassphrase(sftpKeyPrivateKeyPassword); 
   sf.setAllowUnknownKeys(true); 
   return new CachingSessionFactory<LsEntry> (sf); 
}
```

My new code for Session Factory looked like:

```
@Bean 
public SessionFactory<org.apache.sshd.sftp.client.SftpClient.DirEntry> sftpSessionFactory() 
{ 
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();  
    sf.setHost(serverhost); 
    sf.setPort(portname);
    sf.setUser(username); 
    Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource(sftpKeyPrivateKey); 
    sf.setPrivateKey(resource); 
    sf.setPrivateKeyPassphrase(sftpKeyPrivateKeyPassword); 
    sf.setAllowUnknownKeys(true); 
    return new  CachingSessionFactory<org.apache.sshd.sftp.client.SftpClient.DirEntry(sf); 
}
```

Everything else remains same. Old code was working as expected but in new code when i start my service i get below exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session 
at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:291) 
at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:67) 
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$1.createForPool(CachingSessionFactory.java:85) 
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$1.createForPool(CachingSessionFactory.java:82) 
at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.doGetItem(SimplePool.java:206) 
at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.getItem(SimplePool.java:187) ... 23 more Caused by: org.apache.sshd.common.SshException: No more authentication methods available 
at org.apache.sshd.common.future.AbstractSshFuture.verifyResult(AbstractSshFuture.java:127) 
at org.apache.sshd.client.future.DefaultAuthFuture.verify(DefaultAuthFuture.java:39) 
at org.apache.sshd.client.future.DefaultAuthFuture.verify(DefaultAuthFuture.java:32) 
at org.apache.sshd.common.future.VerifiableFuture.verify(VerifiableFuture.java:43) 
at org.apache.sshd.common.future.VerifiableFuture.verify(VerifiableFuture.java:68) 
at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.initClientSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:318) 
at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:281) ... 28 more 
Caused by: org.apache.sshd.common.SshException: No more authentication methods available
```

Comment: Would you mind to reformat the code and stacktrace in your question to make them readable: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks ?

Comment: See this one for more info: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SSHD-945. You probably don't have some SSH algorithm provider lib against your server security.

Comment: Sorry i have updated the question. I just changed Java version from 17 to 11. In Java 11 same code base with same key and same server is still working.

Comment: Spring Integration `6.0.x` doesn't work with Java 11. So, you probably did something else, like downgraded Spring Integration.

Comment: With Java 11 i was using  5.5.15, with Java 17 i am using 6.0.1. Only change in code i did was as above.

Comment: Also instead of LsEntry i am using DirEntry because LsEntry is no longer supported with Spring Integration 6.0.1

Comment: I got the issue with this, with JSCH you can ppk file in putty ssh-rsa. But in Apache we need to have our key starting with -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----. Because inside code this is the beginner apache has in order to load.

Comment: Did it work when you fixed the key?

Comment: Yes Artem, sorry for late response

Comment: Good. I guess you can form it into an answer and add it to your own question here.

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue, with Java 17 changes we have to use DirEntry from Apache instead of LsEntry.
With JSCH you can ppk file in putty ssh-rsa. But in Apache we need to have our key starting with
`-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----`. Because inside code this is the beginner apache has in order to load.

So we can convert our key to OPENSSH private key and it will work as expected.

> ssh-keygen -p -N "" -f /path/to/key